# PropertyGrid showing List<String> properties

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, propertygrid

I have a `PropertyGrid` on my form, one of the properties I'm editing is a String List. I have implemented a `UITypeEditor`, so that when the user clicks the '...' button on that property, a new form appears.

This works really well, except that when the user saves the list, my property suddenly has two sub properties: Capacity and Count

My question is, how do I stop these sub properties being exposed?

Comment: looks like it's not easy to find out what's wrong with what you provided.

Comment: please edit your question with the code you use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably can sublass the `List` and set `[Browsable(false)]` attribute on `Capacity` and `Count` properties, which would prevent them to be shown in the `PropertyGrid`.

Comment: Many thanks, followed your advice, and the properties no longer appear!!